# How do I get the data usage of applications from adb logs?

Tags: automation, adb, ui-automation, bug-reporting, android-data-usage

I want to automate the apps which are running in background or in foreground and how much data the app is consuming.
Where do I get this info in adb logs ? like if any keyword is there for network data usage then it would be helpful for me

Comment: Bugreport is designed to help the app developer understand the problem. The data usage of an app is irrelevant to bug fixing (it is also a privacy relevant data) and thus should not be included in a bug report.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.